# Graphing a curve with any android library

Tags: android, graph, curve

I've found several graphing libraries for android which would be very suitable for my school project e.g. [**GraphView**](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView) 
My task is to display 3 Biorhythm curves on one graph. I looked at many examples and helps but I just couldn't get my head around how to change the code so it will display my biorhythm curve.

```
        // sin curve
    int num = 150;
    GraphViewData[] data = new GraphViewData[num];
    double v = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        v += 0.2;
        data[i] = new GraphViewData(i, Math.sin(v));
    }
```

The three biorhythm cycle equations are:

- physical: sin(2\pi t/23),
- emotional: sin(2\pi t/28),
- intellectual: sin(2\pi t/33),

t = number of days since birth, this number has been calculated from the users input and is stored in a shared preference defined as differenceInDays

It would be awesome if someone could just give me an example, please do ask if I need to be more specific (this is my first time posting on this website) and if you have a suggestion to THE perfect graphing library in android please let me know :D